# My ISP censors connections and recently, tor doesn't connect. What might be the reason?

Tags: configuration, bridge, censorship

```
6/24/2016 21:20:26 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/24/2016 21:56:19 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/24/2016 21:56:28 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
6/24/2016 21:56:28 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
6/24/2016 21:56:30 PM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to IP-ADRESS:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure") 
6/24/2016 22:44:07 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/24/2016 22:44:07 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/24/2016 22:44:07 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Hi there. Your ISP censors connections to the Tor network... and you can't connect to the Tor network. Do you mean you used to be able to connect to Tor using bridges or pluggable transports, and now you can't? Please add some more details to your explanation.

Comment: Also, please don't post anything that might be bridge IP addresses :(

Comment: Those IPs look like they're the default obfs bridges, if your ISP is actually trying to censor Tor and making a reasonable effort then it's quite likely that those are on a blacklist. You'll need to retreive bridges from bridgedb: https://bridges.torproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a very frequent bug in Tor Browser Bundle, check the messages `DisableNetwork is set.` It's **pretty odd, but**: Tor Browser sets DisableNetwork when it's not opened, so Tor instance seems to be intended to run only when the *browser itself* is active. Run **the browser** and don't close it - give it some time and send a full log if it will not work even that way. Also a pluggable transports and bridges can be of help to you